# error while adding web part : error is list parameters have been changed

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

this is my error i got when i tried to add a web part:

```
   401 Unauthorized

  [SPException: The parameters in this list have been recently changed. Refresh your 
   browser before editing the list.]
```

Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.BaseFieldControl.OnLoad (EventArgs e)
       33,595,648
        System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive () +71
        System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive () +190
        System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive () +190
        System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive () +190
        System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive () +190
       System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive () +190
        System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive () +190
       System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive () +190
       System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive () +190
       System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive () +190
       System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive () +190
       System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive () +190
       System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive () +190
       System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive () +190
       System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive () +190
       System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive () +190
        System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain (Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, 
        Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) 3178

```
  [SPException]: The parameters in this list have been recently changed. Refresh   
  your browser before editing the list.
```

to Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.BaseFieldControl.OnLoad (EventArgs e)
     System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive to ()
        System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive to ()
        System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive to ()
        System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive to ()
        System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive to ()
        System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive to ()
       System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive to ()
        System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive to ()
       System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive to ()
       System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive to ()
       System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive to ()
       System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive to ()
       System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive to ()
       System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive to ()
       System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive to ()
       System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive to ()
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain (Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint,
       Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

```
   [HttpUnhandledException]: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' 
   was    
     to System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError (Exception e)
```

at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain (Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint,
       Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest (Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, 
     Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
     System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest to ()
     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest (HttpContext context)
     to

```
   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.
    IExecutionStep.Execute()
```

at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep (IExecutionStep step, Boolean &
        completedSynchronously)
     ->

Comment: what does your webpart do?

Comment: is not in web part in HttpModule

Comment: but when does the error occur?